# ebean query with setParameter

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have a query using a Ebean Finder object. this is a working version:

```
public static Finder<Long, Device> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Device.class);
```

.

```
public static Page<Device> find(int page, String sorting, String order) {

    return
            find.where()
                    .orderBy(sorting + " " + order)
                    .findPagingList(10)
                    .setFetchAhead(false)
                    .getPage(page);
}
```

but now I want to make it SQLInjection-safe by using setParameter function, I tried this, but didn't work. would be great to know what I have wrong.

```
public static Page<Device> find(int page, String sorting, String order) {

    return
            find.where()
                    .orderBy(":sorting :order")
                    .setParameter("sorting", sorting)
                    .setParameter("order", order)
                    .findPagingList(10)
                    .setFetchAhead(false)
                    .getPage(page);

}
```

**UPDATE:**

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898387/3716114) ,

> "The problem is you can't use named parameters to set the ORDER in an HQL (or SQL) query."

If true, this keeps my code vulnerable to SQL injection! so what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell how secure Ebean is, but you can see that the string passed to orderBy is parsed : [OrderBy.java](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/avaje/ebean/OrderBy.java)

If I wrote, for example :

```
find.where()
  .ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%")
  .orderBy("1;DROP TABLE company")
  .fetch("company")
  .findPagingList(pageSize)
  .setFetchAhead(false)
  .getPage(page);
```

I get this exception :

```
[RuntimeException: Expecting a max of 2 words in [[1;DROP, TABLE, company]] but got 3]
```

Comment: thanks for the source code, it shows that for the OrderBy property, it is not possible to mess with the parameters!